# Is it possible to use multiprocessing.Event to implement a synchronization barrier for pool of processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Is it possible to use multiprocessing.Event to implement a synchronization barrier for pool of processes? I am using Python 2.7. But it looks like the Event is not shared between processes.
Is something wrong with my code?

```
def test_func(event):
    event.wait()
    return datetime.datetime.now()

def log_result(result):
    result_list.append(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool_size=10
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size)
    event = multiprocessing.Manager().Event()
    for _ in xrange(pool_size):
        pool.apply_async(test_func, args=(event,), callback=log_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()   
    time.sleep(5)
    event.set()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have dead-lock: pool.join() waits for started processes and all processes wait on event.wait(). Sedd pool join:

join()

```
Wait for the worker processes to exit
```

Basically you have to move "pool.join()" after "event.set()" and all should be OK.